# ASP.NET Update GridView statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, updatecommand

I am using VS2005 C# and SQL Server 2005.

I have a GridView and this is my current Update statement:

`UpdateCommand="UPDATE [UserData] SET [UserID] = @UserIDe, [Username] = @Username, [Age] = @Age, [MemberType]=@MemberType WHERE [UserID] = @UserID`

The above statement will update the user row identify by `UserID`.

However, I would like the variable `UserID` to be editable, thus if I edit my `UserID` while updating the table, the row will not be updated because that particular `UserID` may not exist.

How can I use the `UpdateCommand` and update the row by identifying the `row number` of the edited row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by tracking all of the original values. Visual Studio will do this for you if you use the wizard to generate your SQL statements, and you select the "use optimistic concurrency" option as shown [here.](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/implementing-optimistic-concurrency-with-the-sqldatasource-vb)

An example of the generated SQL can be found [here](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/implementing-optimistic-concurrency-vb).

Code sample from the page:

```
UPDATE Products SET
    ProductName = @ProductName,
    UnitPrice = @UnitPrice
WHERE
    ProductID = @original_ProductID AND
    ProductName = @original_ProductName AND
    UnitPrice = @original_UnitPrice
```

Reading through the article, you should be able to apply the same type of query to your situation, as using the original values should allow you to bypass the need for a primary key. However, I should point out that having an editable identification key is a very bad design, as you can't guarantee it is unique.  you can very easily end updating more than one record, along with a whole host of other issues.

Answer (score 1):

Underneath the GridView there is the table needs to have at least one Unique ID in order to update a record. If you need to edit the UserID, you need to have a fixed key in your table. At least name it as UserKey. I think GridView could only edit and update data as long as you have a pointer to that row. Otherwise, remove the UserID from the DataKeyNames collection and assign it with the columns you think are unique and does not change.